# How to use expect in playwright js?

Tags: testing, puppeteer, chai, playwright

I have following code written in puppeteer with chai. How could it be written in playwright js?

```
const expect = require("chai").expect;

const puppeteer = require("puppeteer");
(async () => {
  const browser = await puppeteer.launch({
    headless: false,
    slowMo: 500, // slow down by 500ms
  });
  const page = await browser.newPage();
  const navigationPromise = page.waitForNavigation()
  // Go to the web page
  await page.goto("https://www.test.com");
  await navigationPromise;


  //Look for navigation point
  await page.screenshot({ path: "navigation.jpg" });
  const text = await page.$eval('.top--right', ele => ele.textContent);
  expect(text).to.not.include('top-bar');
  console.log("Navigation is deployed");
  await browser.close();
})()
```

Comment: `const navigationPromise = page.waitForNavigation()` should be removed. `goto` already does this.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to use regex to check for the text so something like this for your expect:
`expect(text).not.toContainText(/top-bar/);`

Or if you only want to check for the exact text then you can skip the regex and just directly put it there.
`expect(text).not.toContainText('top-bar');`

Answer (score 0):

```
import {test, expect} from "@playwright/test"

test("your test title here", async({page}) => { //default : page fixture  will create a browser instance 
    await page.goto("https://www.test.com");
    await page.screenshot({ path: "navigation.jpg" });

    const text = await page.locator('.top--right').textContent();
    expect(text).not.toContain('expected text');

})
```